# Fetching non-standard refs

Tags: git

I'm trying to fetch some commits from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+log/branch-heads/5359 which is a non-standard ref, a "pseudo-branch" I guess you could call it.

Ultimately I want to check out commit `93081d5`

By non-standard I mean that it's not a branch (branches would be under `refs/heads`)

If I just clone the repo using `git clone` the commit `93081d5` is not available.

To fetch commits from this "pseudo branch" (all of them at once) I tried this:

```
git fetch origin -v "+refs/branch_heads/*:refs/branch_heads/*"
```

but it had no effect, none of the remote `refs/branch_heads` became visible in `git show-ref` and `git checkout 93081d5` still could not find the commit.

I did read the docs about git refspecs, and don't understand why my command above doesn't actually fetch all the remote refs under `refs/branch_heads`.

How can I fetch all the remote refs under `refs/branch_heads/*`?

I can fetch just one such ref with `git fetch origin refs/branch-heads/5359` but seems it should be possible to fetch them all at once.

I also want the ref to become available in local refs as shown in `git show-ref`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Argh, user error! This works fine: ```
git fetch origin "+refs/branch-heads/*:refs/branch-heads/*"
``` but I was using this: ```
git fetch origin "+refs/branch_heads/*:refs/branch_heads/*"
``` Note the underscore (wrong) instead of the dash (right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cloning that repository, running `git ls-remote origin` shows that you want:

```
dfa57fb060c76434875cc5bf8d38b2e838980df7        refs/branch-heads/5359
```

We can fetch that reference like this:

```
$ git fetch origin refs/branch-heads/5359
From https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc
 * branch                  refs/branch-heads/5359 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

After which the commit is available:

```
$ git show 93081d5
commit 93081d594f7efff72958a79251f53731b99e902b
Author: Evan Shrubsole <eshr@webrtc.org>
Date:   Thu Oct 27 13:05:44 2022 +0200

    [Merge M108] Ensure video frame buffer is still decodable before decoding

    This ensures that if for some reason, the frame buffer becomes
    undecodable while waiting to decode a frame, the decoding is halted.
    This also guards against receiving an empty temporal unit from the frame
    buffer, even though this should never happen when the frame buffer has a
    decodable temporal unit.

    (cherry picked from commit 8fe5579136c82b558022fe7d1393fa248b151eae)

...
```

Comment: Thank you @larsks but how do I fetch all such refs?